# How do I add to the value of an integrer?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, double, java.util.scanner

For a school assignment in Java, we're pretending to code the meny at a Spa Reception where the customer is supposed to add which treatments they've chosen and it's supposed to be added to the total cost. We're given a base of code (I've written the switch statement). We're supposed to use the literals declared in the code when calculating the cost. I'm having trouble figuring out how to add the value of a treatment to the total cost (see the ** parts in bold). I've been trying to figure out a way to add the value to the cost but I just can't seem to figure it out...

Here's the code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SpaReception{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double cost = 0;
    int treatment = 0;

    final double faceMask = 600.00;
    final double footMassage = 300.00;
    final double fullBodyMassage = 1500.00;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  //create scanner for input
    System.out.println("Type in which treatment you've gotten ");
    System.out.println("Face mask: 1");
    System.out.println("Foot massage: 2");
    System.out.println("Full body massage: 3");
    System.out.println("Cancel: -1");
    treatment = input.nextInt();

    switch (treatments) {
      case 1: 
        ***add the value of faceMask to cost***
        break;
      case 2:
       ***add the value of footMassage to cost***
        break;
      case 3:
        ***add the value of fullBodyMassage to cost***
        break;
      case 4:
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("The cost is: "+cost);
  }
}
```

Since I can't add a new constant (say "sumOne = sum + faceMask") and work it out that way, I'm really lost as to what to do and how to add to the value of cost.

Comment: `cost += faceMask;`

Comment: *"Since I can't add a new constant"* - you don't have to. Just use `cost = cost + whatever`

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't add a new variable to the code, we can just add the values of treatments to the actual cost. Since it is a 'Switch Case' statement, unless we need to repeat this process again, the value of the selected Treatment will be added to cost which is 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SpaReception{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double cost = 0;
    int treatment = 0;

    final double faceMask = 600.00;
    final double footMassage = 300.00;
    final double fullBodyMassage = 1500.00;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  //create scanner for input
    System.out.println("Type in which treatment you've gotten ");
    System.out.println("Face mask: 1");
    System.out.println("Foot massage: 2");
    System.out.println("Full body massage: 3");
    System.out.println("Cancel: -1");
    treatment = input.nextInt();

    switch (treatment) {
      case 1: 
      cost += faceMask;
        break;
      case 2:
      cost += footMassage;
        break;
      case 3:
        cost += fullBodyMassage;
        break;
      case 4:
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("The cost is: "+cost);
  }
}
```

This is what i think will solve the issue of not adding another variable and still getting a calculation for the Menu. I hope this is what you need and helps.

P.S: The Variable 'treatment' is mentioned differently in either Switch Case or at the time of Declaration.

Comment: Omg yes thank you! It seems I've completely forgotten the += operator existed, which is exactly what I was looking for – thank you so much. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Check for multiple inputs.

Here is an example.

```java
double cost = 0;
int treatment = 0;

final double faceMask = 600.00;
final double footMassage = 300.00;
final double fullBodyMassage = 1500.00;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  //create scanner for input
System.out.println("Type in which treatment you've gotten ");
System.out.println("Face mask: 1");
System.out.println("Foot massage: 2");
System.out.println("Full body massage: 3");

input = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
for (String s : input.tokens().toArray(String[]::new))
    switch (s) {
        case "1" -> cost += faceMask;
        case "2" -> cost += footMassage;
        case "3" -> cost += fullBodyMassage;
    }

System.out.println("The cost is: "+cost);
```

Output

```
Type in which treatment you've gotten 
Face mask: 1
Foot massage: 2
Full body massage: 3
1 2 3
The cost is: 2400.0
```